# Отключить кулеры видеокарты

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nvidia

Установил себе Ubuntu 18.04, и запустив систему, услышал как громко работает кулер моей видеокарты (Nvidia GeForce 1060), посмотрел по датчикам - кулеры крутятся стабильно на 2000 оборотов, что крайне ненормально, так как в системе кулеры вообще не должны работать за ненадобностью.

Температуры проверял, все в норме, нагрузок также нет. Отключить видеокарту и заменить на встроенную не получается - убунту видит только Nvidia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше откатитьтся, 18 убунту какая то все еще не стабильная(часто проблемы с программами). Попробуй изменить драйвер на проприетарный(тот что от nvidia)

Comment: спасибо, работает